# $g(f(x))=x$, find whether f,g are injective/surjective/both

Tags: calculus, functions

> let $f: \ A \to B \ , \ g: B \to A$ s.t $\forall x \in A$ $g(f(x))=x$.

Is f is bijection? surjection? both?
Same for g.

I started by defining f to be constant function - $f(x)=C$, so we get $g(f(x))=g(c)$, means that $g(f(x))$ is constant, but I don't how to continue.

What should I do?

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$g$ is surjective; $f$ is injective. The proof is fair straightforward; below I prove $f$ is injective.

Let $f(x)=f(y)$, then $gf(x)=gf(y)$. But this implies $x=y$, hence $f$ is injective. I left the other talks for you (providing an example $f$ is not surjective).